# Formatting word for kindle

Tags: kindle, formatting

I've written a book and uploaded it to Kindle. I have two books available already and formatted them without issue. This time, Kindle Preview looked fine. When the book went live, I checked it on my smartphone, and there were spaces in sentences which were not on the preview. I contacted Kindle, and they said I had used hard returns.

If I `^9` to expose the paragraphs, and then soft return them, I still have the issue of justifying. The sentences with few words go at each end of the page!

How can I resolve this?